# Checking if structure has values in c

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I have the following linked list implementation:

```
typedef struct stringNode{
    char *key;
    char *value;
    struct stringNode *next;
} stringNode;
```

The linked list should start empty, so I initialize it with this:

```
stringNode *linkedList= (stringNode *)malloc(sizeof(stringNode));
```

Now, I want to add values to the list. This is done in a function. It is defined as

```
void setString(stringNode *linkedList, char *key, char *value{
    stringNode *p = linkedList;
    stringNode *newNode = (stringNode *)malloc(sizeof(stringNode));
    newNode -> key = key;
    newNode -> value = value;
    newNode -> next = NULL;
    while (p->next != NULL) {
        p = p -> next;
    }
    p -> next = newNode;
}
```

But, if the list is empty, then for some reason I get a segmentation fault that seems to come from accessing `p -> next`. I have also tried to check if `p -> value` is not null, and that also gives a segmentation fault. What am I doing wrong? And how do I fix it?

Comment: You should check if `p` (`linkedList`) is not null.

Comment: I can assume it isn't null because I know how it is defined

Comment: Your initialisation is lacking. You need to set the members to initial values. `malloc` doesn't guarantee that.

Comment: I can't set the members to an initial value, because when it is defined, I still don't the the values it is supposed to have

Comment: As cheateh said. You shall initialize things after malloc, in particular set 'linkedList->next = NULL;'. However, this is still not a usual implementation. In a usual implementation linkedList is initialized to NULL and reset after having added the first element.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but don't use dummy-elements at beginning of linked lists. It is just an ugly hack to pretend that you are not using a pointer to a pointer, AKA double pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined values for newNode, but you never define initial values for linkedList (p).  Therefore, the initial `p->next`  will contain random garbage.
Either ensure you set this to NULL the first time you allocate it, or if you are expecting things to be zero'd before using them, use calloc instead of malloc.

Calloc is slower than malloc, partially because it is zeroing.

Comment: I have tried doing something like
`stringNode *linkedList = (stringNode *)calloc(1,sizeof(stringNode));
`
but it still doesn't work

Comment: Nevermind, it does work, I just had an error in another part of the code and just now managed to catch it

Comment: This is why we usually ask for a [mre].